# Android application using big amount of CPU, also for a simple static fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a simple application with *MainActivity* for managing the fragments and *LogIn* fragment, when I run the application in my device, I notice that the application is vary slow (for every typing of the user, there is delay of 0.5 - 1 sec for character to show in the login page), I think the reason is a large use of the CPU, I saw that my app taking a large CPU use even for a static fragment, for example the login page.

What can be the reason?
How can I get information about running trades in my application?

I run the application using Android Studio, Run App, Device (LG-F240 with Android ver. 4.4.2)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String logIn = "LogInFragment";
    public static final String MainMap = "MainMap";
    public static FragmentManager manager;
    private SharedPreferences get_user_prefences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor user_prefences;
    private static final String PREFERENCES = "user";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.container);

        get_user_prefences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        user_prefences = get_user_prefences.edit();

        String save_password = get_user_prefences.getString("auto_log_in","true");

        if(save_password.equals(true)){
            switchToSignUp();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, save_password ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            manager = getFragmentManager();
            LogInFragment logInFragment = new LogInFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            //first we add the login fragment for the first login
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,logInFragment,logIn);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    //switch between the singin fragment to the singup fragment
    public void switchToSignUp(){
        MainMap mainMap = new MainMap();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.add(R.id.container,mainMap,MainMap);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**LogInFragment.java**

```
public class LogInFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,ResultInterface {

        private View rootView;
        private TextView tv_email,tv_pass;
        private EditText et_email,et_pass;
        private Button b_login;
        private String id,email,ifChecked;
        private Typeface font;
        private CheckBox cb_remember;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor user_prefences;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;
        private static final String PREFERENCES = "user";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            //all the login elements
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
            tv_email = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            tv_pass = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pass);
            et_email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
            et_pass = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
            b_login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_login);
            cb_remember = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_remember);

            //check if the auto login checked
            user_prefences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            tv_email.setTypeface(font);
            tv_pass.setTypeface(font);
            b_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void result(JSONObject jObj) {

            String massage = null;
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("message");
                massage = (String) jObj.get("message");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(new String(massage).equals("OK")){
                try {
                    //get the id and the
                    id = (String) jObj.get("id");
                    email = (String) jObj.get("email");

                    //Insert the information to the database
                    user_prefences.putString("id", id);
                    user_prefences.putString("email" ,email);
                    user_prefences.commit();

                    if(cb_remember.isChecked()){
                        user_prefences.putString("auto_log_in" ,"true");
                        user_prefences.commit();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).switchToSignUp();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "wrong password, try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == b_login){
                //check if there is internet
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                    //Resizable-array implementation of the List interface, NameValuePair - A simple class encapsulating an attribute/value pair
                    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

                    //BasicNameValuePair -Default Constructor taking a name and a value. The value may be null.
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",et_email.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",et_pass.getText().toString()));

                    //call to function closeKeyboard for closing the soft keyboard after getting the text
                    closeKeyboard(getActivity(),et_email.getWindowToken());

                    //create new connection for checking the username and password
                    new Connection(this,"http://loclist.com/android/login.php").execute(nameValuePairs);
                }else{
                    //error massage for the network
                    Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void closeKeyboard(Context c, IBinder windowToken) {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) c.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
        }

        private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }

    }
```

Layout of the LogInFragment:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#99ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"
            android:text="@string/LoginEmail"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:width="100dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Insert your username"
            android:id="@+id/et_email" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_pass"
            android:text="@string/LoginPassword"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:width="100dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Insert your password"
            android:id="@+id/et_password" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/remember_me"
        android:id="@+id/cb_remember"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:id="@+id/b_login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should measure the times of the different parts of your code and also check if views are redrawn/relayouted multiple times.

Comment: Thank you oberflansch, How can I check if the views are redrawn/relayouted multiple times?

Comment: This is not directly performance-related but if you are using AppCompat, you should use support Fragments and getSupportFragmentManager() instead of the native fragments.